# Issue installing Software

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and I have been trying to fix an error somewhere in the install process. No matter how I install (software center, Terminal) it displays an error message close to this:

installAr

```
chives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package libept1.4.12:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 242784 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libept1.4.12_1.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libept1.4.12:amd64 (1.0.12) ...
Selecting previously unselected package sgml-data.
Preparing to unpack .../sgml-data_2.0.9-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking sgml-data (2.0.9-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docbook-xml.
Preparing to unpack .../docbook-xml_4.5-7.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking docbook-xml (4.5-7.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librarian0.
Preparing to unpack .../librarian0_0.8.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking librarian0 (0.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rarian-compat.
Preparing to unpack .../rarian-compat_0.8.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rarian-compat (0.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package synaptic.
Preparing to unpack .../synaptic_0.81.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking synaptic (0.81.1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.26+nmu4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Scrollkeeper was installed, forcing re-registration of all documents.
Unregistering 33 doc-base files, re-registering 33 doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up xserver-common-lts-raring (3:5) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt to /usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt by xserver-common-lts-raring'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt' with
  different file `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package xserver-common-lts-raring (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libept1.4.12:amd64 (1.0.12) ...
Setting up sgml-data (2.0.9-1) ...
Setting up librarian0 (0.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up synaptic (0.81.1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.26+nmu4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up docbook-xml (4.5-7.2) ...
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.26+nmu4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up rarian-compat (0.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
Error in function: 
Setting up xserver-common-lts-raring (3:5) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt to /usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt by xserver-common-lts-raring'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt' with
  different file `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package xserver-common-lts-raring (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

In Software Center it displays that "Package Operation Failed"

It does install the programs I want, but I would really like to get rid of the error message.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? What are you trying to install?

Comment: Its really anything @mniess. Ive installed everything from Docky, to netflix and it always displays the same info.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The other link doesnt work. It displays the error message    mv: cannot stat ‘/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt’: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/xorg`

Comment: @mniess `sudo apt-get -f install` won't work.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It displayed     ls: cannot access /usr/ib/xorg: No such file or directory

Comment: @mniess I tried your suggestion and it seems to be working. Im going to try a couple more things and make sure.

Comment: @user283899 Okay, I added my suggestion has an official answer. If this solved your problem, please verify that it did.

Answer (score 0):

Repair the package management by running

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will complete the installation of packages that are not installed or configured completely.